# How to obtain full access to remote windows filesystem?

Tags: windows, file-sharing

I have administrative rights on remote computer. Nevertheless, I see only `Users` share on it, and my personal subfolder under it. No subfolders of other users, no `Common` subfolder and no dollar shares (like `C$`).

How to get all this?

Comment: This `Users` share a network drive because that seems to indicated your connected to an active domain which means your only a local Administrator not a Administrator on the domain and there is a huge difference.  We need more information.

Comment: Are you on a domain?  There's no such thing as a "common" subfolder by default, and the admin shares (like C$) are purposefully invisible, so I wouldn't expect to "see" either of these.  Also, if memory serves, those admin shares are disabled by default in Windows Vista+ if you're not on a domain.

Answer (score 0):

When you access the computer by UNC you will only see shared folders. To access the C: you have to put c$ at the end e.g. `\\pc-name\c$`